# CAKeyFrameAnimation with different time duration on a particular UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, core-animation, uibezierpath

I want to animate a image onto a UIBezierPath with duration of 12 seconds. I am using CAKeyframeAnimation for that. My problem is that i want to animate image for 2 sec from  starting point to firstPoint, for 4 sec from first point to second point, for 4 sec from second point to third point and for 2 sec from third point to end point. How can i do this? Here is my code.

```
CGPoint startingpoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x + 98, self.bounds.size.height -20);
CGPoint firstPoint = CGPointMake(startingpoint.x + 20,startingpoint.y);
CGPoint secondpoint = CGPointMake(firstPoint.x + 30,firstPoint.y - 80);
CGPoint thirdpoint = CGPointMake(secondpoint.x + 50, secondpoint.y + 80);
CGPoint endPoints = CGPointMake(thirdpoint.x + 20,thirdpoint.y);

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:startingpoint];
[path addLineToPoint:firstPoint];
[path addLineToPoint:secondpoint];
[path addLineToPoint:thirdpoint];
[path addLineToPoint:endPoints];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation1 = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation1.duration = 10;
animation1.path = path.CGPath;
animation1.autoreverses = NO;
animation1.repeatCount = 0;
[myImageView.layer addAnimation:animation1 forKey:@"position"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a few things on your animation. Specifically you're not setting any `keyTimes` or values on your `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Even though they're optional, Core Animation doesn't know that you want a value changed at 2 seconds and then again 4 seconds later. You have to tell the animation what you want.

To do that you need two `NSArray`s of equal length. The first will have the times for your key frames *as a factor of your animation's total time*:

```
CFTimeInterval d = 12.0f; // 12 seconds total time
NSArray * keyTimes = @[@(0), @(2/d), @(6/d), @(10/d), @(1.0)];
```

And the other will be a list of values (in this case CGPoint wrapped in NSValues because you're animating a CGPoint typed property) to which those `keyTimes` will correspond:

```
NSArray * pointValues = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startingPoint], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:firstPoint], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:secondPoint], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:thirdPoint], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint]];
```

Finally set them on the animation:

```
animation1.keyTimes = keyTimes;
animation1.values = values;
```

If you want to get really fancy you can also specify an n-1 length array of timing functions for the timing of each value change between the provided key times:

```
CAMediaTimingFunction * linear = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
CAMediaTimingFunction * easeIn = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
CAMediaTimingFunction * fastEaseInOut = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.30f :0.92f :0.86f :0.95f];

NSArray * timingFunctions = @[easeIn, linear, linear, fastEaseInOut];
animation1.timingFunctions = timingFunctions;
```